# What's up with the long exhaust stack I saw on a Cessna Caravan?

Tags: aircraft-identification, feature-identification, turboprop, cessna-208

Our local airport is regularly visited by Cessna caravans flying cargo. This week I saw one parked outside the FBO building that had its exhaust stack bent down to lead under the cowling, where it was connected to a duct suspended from the underside of the fuselage. The duct was perhaps a foot in diameter and ran all the way back to where the tailcone began. Every other Caravan I have ever seen has the exhaust stack exiting the cowling on one side and then terminating. What's up with the ducted exhaust?

Comment: Caravans or Grand Caravans? Is this particular plane a turboprop, I would imagine so judging by the size of the exhaust?

Comment: https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/14088/this-unique-epa-plane-is-monitoring-toxic-waste-dumps-around-houston   Was it this plane?

Comment: That's an answer.  It's to clear the exhaust of atmospheric sampling intakes.

Comment: @md88fan yes yes that's it!!!

Comment: Holy cow! That’s a lucky catch. Glad I could help.

Comment: Somebody write an answer.  @md88fan go for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The aircraft you saw, "[ASPECT](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/14088/this-unique-epa-plane-is-monitoring-toxic-waste-dumps-around-houston)," is a contractor operated Cessna Grand Caravan used by the EPA to monitor sites of active or possible [CBRN disasters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBRN_defense).

[image]

The reason for the long exhaust stack is simply to keep exhaust gasses from interfering with the sensors on board. As I write this, the aircraft is flying over New Orleans, likely assessing damage from Hurricane Ida:

[image]
Source: [flightaware.com](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/N9738B/history/20210905/2033Z/KBTR/KBPT); Sep 5th, 2021

The mission is similar, though not identical, to the Bell 412s operated by the Dept of State, equipped with sensors to measure radiation- baselines are established for cities and these helicopters can be deployed in the unlikely scenario that radiological material is stolen or a nuclear/radiological weapon is suspected to be nearby. Hope this helps!

Update: per StephenS, this is also common on aerial survey aircraft, but since it has been identified as the ASPECT aircraft, the above remains true.

Comment: Yes it does! this was great.

Comment: This is also common on aerial survey planes to keep hot, dirty exhaust away from the expensive cameras.